# OrderSend() opening multiple positions in one go - how to prevent this from happening in MQL4?

Tags: mql4

When I use an `OrderSend()` function in MQL4, it opens 10 orders in one go in the MetaTrader Terminal 4 Strategy Tester.

How do I ensure that the MQL4-code opens one and only one order?

Comment: You need to provide your code to enable people to help. Without this it is impossible to accurately determine the problem.

Comment: I would normally vote to close here, but it has been through a close/open cycle already. I can't see why it would be reopened, but I agree with @PaulB - this feels like it needs more detail. Since it has been quiet for a few days, I suspect it has been abandoned.

Comment: I am going to vote to close here - the question is abandoned, and it would need an action from the author.